# Install package "png" in R/ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, libpng

(Under ubuntu), I try:

```
install.packages("png")
```

and get:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/kaveh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/png/libs/png.so':
  libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I thought it has to due with `libpng` being obselete but I have already installed it from [this link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libpng.html) using:

```
./configure 
make check
make install
```

so I don't really know what more to do~

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be missing the `libpng*` headers in order to build from source.  On my machine(s), I have package [libpng12-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng12-dev) installed.  Ensure you have it too, and then try installing `png` again.

Also note that

```
R> capabilities()["png"]
 png 
TRUE 
R>
```

so your default build of R should already have the ability to create png files.

Comment: You certainly know more about it, but doesn't the error message suggest that the system is looking for libpng16 instead of libpng12? I think that libpng16* is distributed with the new xenial release.

Comment: That's why I suggested `libpng*` -- the OP will need whichever `-dev` package corresponds to his runtime package.

Comment: Ok, I think my problem is specific to my ubuntu. I must have broken something in it~

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem today. As suggested [here](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/png-R-library:-resolving-libpng.so-error), I resolved the problem by first launching R with `sudo`, and then simply doing `install.packages('png')`.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is here `dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)`, it could not find png.so in your DLLpath. DLL are also called 'dynamic shared objects' ('DSO') in Unix-alikes systems. The DLLpath can be added by `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`.

When you install libpng,

```
./configure prefix=/home/usrname
make check
make install
```

then add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/usrname/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`
I hope I had made it clear.