# Unable to load arm package in R

Tags: r

I have successfully installed arm. When trying to load the arm package, however, I get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arm’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/png/libs/png.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/png/libs/png.so, 6): Symbol not found: _inflateValidate
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/png/libs/png.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/png/libs/png.so
```

I have already restarted R and updated all packages. Why is that and how can I resolve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you recently upgraded R? I encountered a similar issue before following an upgrade. Try removing and re-installing the package. If that doesn't work, try to fully delete and re-install R.

Comment: Yes, I have removed and re-installed it. I will fully delete and re-install R then.

Comment: It does not help, unfortunately, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902205/install-package-png-in-r-ubuntu).

In summary, you might be missing the png headers for another package. Try running `capabilities()` to see if "png" is TRUE. If not, check which `libpng*-dev` packages (eg system packages) are installed and install them if they are missing (I'm not sure which version you need so might need to try several).